# Como puedo poner un hipervinculo en lista HTML5?

Tags: html5

Tengo una lista ordenada en html5, queria saber como puedo hacer que al hacer click en el texto que esta entre los "li" me mande a una pagina externa. Estoy usando dreamweaver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por curiosidad, ¿cómo pondrías un hipervínculo/enlace en otra parte del código?

Comment: si utilizas etiquetas solo colocas algo como esto : `<a href="https://es.stackoverflow.com">Click para visitar Stack OverFlow en Español</a>`, ese seria un hipervinculo hacia esta pagina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es redireccion a otra pagina al hacer click en el texto utiliza la etiqueta

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="ruta.com"> Nombre de la pagina </a> </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para cada elemento de la lista le colocas la etiqueta:

```
<a></a>
```

sería así:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></li>
<li><a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools.com!</a></li>
</ul>
```